# Implementing react-hook-forms and react-select with radio buttons and multi inputs combo

Tags: input, controls, react-select, react-hook-form

Ready for a complicated one?

Using react-hook-forms and react-select using creatable (user creates multiple inputs on the fly)

I'm trying to implement a form that uses an option on 4 radio buttons, 2 of which reveal multi inputs (inputs that use react-select where the user can create multiple entries, not a dropdown) and trying to keep track of both the radio inputs and the multi inputs in the final useForm() object. I also need to be able to remove them if the user changes their mind or resets the form in total. Right now, the key values of registrationTypes changes when I change radioTwo and enter inputs. I also don't know how to remove user inputs. I'm using Controller to read the entries (although I've heard if you're using native HTML checkbox input, you have to use Register?) . Here's the code:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Creatable from 'react-select/creatable'
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import { ErrorRow } from '../util/FormStyles'
import { FormRulesProps } from '../util/formRuleTypes'
import FormError from './FormError'

const registrationTypes = [
  {
    label: 'Allow anyone with the link to register',
    value: 'radioOne',
  },
  {
    label: 'Allow anyone with this email domain to register:',
    value: 'radioTwo',
  },
  { label: 'Allow anyone with this code to register:', value: 'radioThree' },
  {
    label: 'Define eligible users manually through eligibilty file.',
    value: 'radioFour',
  },
]

const RegistrationEligibilty = () => {
  const {
    control,
    reset,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<any>()

  const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState({ regType: '' })

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  const handleSelected = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedRadio({ ...selectedRadio, regType: value })
  }

  return (
    <RegistrationEligibiltyContainer>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormRow>
            <RadioWrapper>
              {registrationTypes.map((rt) => (
                <Controller
                  key={rt.value}
                  control={control}
                  name="radio"
                  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }: any) => (
                    <RadioGroup
                      // @ts-ignore
                      value={value}
                      onChange={(e: any) =>
                        onChange(e.target.value, handleSelected(rt.value))
                      }
                    >
                      <Radio
                        name={rt.value}
                        type="radio"
                        value={rt.value}
                        checked={selectedRadio.regType === rt.value}
                      />
                      <TextRow
                        text={rt.label}
                        style={{ paddingLeft: '10px' }}
                      />
                      {selectedRadio.regType === 'radioTwo' &&
                        rt.value === 'radioTwo' && (
                          <FormRow>
                            <div style={{ width: '90%' }}>
                            <Controller
                              name={rt.value}
                       
                              control={control}
                              render={({ field }) => (
                               <Creatable
                                  {...field}
                                  isMulti
                                  options={field.value}
                                  value={field.value}
                                  placeholder="Select domains"
                                   />
                                 )}
                                />
                            </div>
                          </FormRow>
                        )}
                      {selectedRadio.regType === 'radioThree' &&
                        rt.value === 'radioThree' && (
                          <FormRow>
                            <div style={{ width: '90%' }}>
                              <Controller
                                name={rt.value}
                               control={control}
                               render={({ field }) => (
                               <Creatable
                                  {...field}
                                  isMulti
                                  options={field.value}
                                  value={field.value}
                                  placeholder="Select codes"
                                 />
                                )}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </FormRow>
                        )}
                    </RadioGroup>
                  )}
                />
              ))}
            </RadioWrapper>
          </FormRow>
        </FormContent>
      </form>
    </RegistrationEligibiltyContainer>
  )
}

export default RegistrationEligibilty
```

The result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMOQb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> I also need to be able to remove them if the user changes their mind or resets the form in total

If the component is unmounted, the value of the component is not included in the result. Make sure your `Creatable` is unmounted when the relevant radio is not selected

Comment: I'm trying to understand how react-hook-forms does mounting and unmounting.